# Python 3 migration of binary string

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a string `binary = '0000010011101010100111000101101010000100000011101010100111000101101010000111110000000000010000000000010000010001000011010000101100001111100000000000000000000000001011001100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'`

in python 2 when i do `''.join(chr(int(binary[i * 8:i * 8 + 8], 2)) for i in range(len(binary) // 8))` on it I get `'\x04\xea\x9cZ\x84\x0e\xa9\xc5\xa8|\x00@\x04\x11\r\x0b\x0f\x80\x00\x00,\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` while in Python 3 I get `'\x04ê\x9cZ\x84\x0e©Å¨|\x00@\x04\x11\r\x0b\x0f\x80\x00\x00,À\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` . Note the difference in first part.

Now I know this is because of for `i=0` in for loop you end up with chr(234) which gives different results in python 2 and 3. So to circumvent this problem I ended up doing `b''.join(bytes([int(binary[i * 8:i * 8 + 8], 2)]) for i in range(len(binary) // 8))` in python 3 which gives me the same string as 2 with a 'b' prefix. I am having problems getting rid of this b. Basically how will I get (TL:DR)
`'\x04\xea\x9cZ\x84\x0e\xa9\xc5\xa8|\x00@\x04\x11\r\x0b\x0f\x80\x00\x00,\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` from `b'\x04\xea\x9cZ\x84\x0e\xa9\xc5\xa8|\x00@\x04\x11\r\x0b\x0f\x80\x00\x00,\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` in Python 3

Comment: Assuming s is the string, wont `int(s, 2).to_bytes((len(s)+7) // 8, byteorder='big')` do the trick?

Comment: @GuilhermeMarthe this worked! thanks!